# Unexpected output after reading from a binary file in turbo c++

Tags: c++, file-io, binaryfiles, file-handling, turbo-c++

After I have written into a file when reading it I get unexpected output.
The code I wrote is :

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct test
{
    char que[100];
    char ans[20];
};

int main()
{
    test s, d;
    clrscr();
    ofstream out("test.dat", ios::binary | ios::app);
    ifstream in("test.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
    strcpy(s.que, "2.How many ways the letters of the word abas be arranged to  form words with or without meaning");
    strcpy(s.ans, "180");
    out.write((char*) &s, sizeof(test));

    while(!in.eof())
    {
        in.getline((char*) &d, sizeof(test));
        cout << d.que << '\n' << d.ans;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The output that I get is :

```
2.How many ways the letters of the word abas be arranged to form words with or w
ithout meaning
180
180
```

This is the output I get along with some arbitrary characters in between.

What have I done wrong? Why is the string that I stored in `s.ans` written into `s.que` as well?

Comment: [while(!in.eof())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)  may be not related to your errors. But when please will you take the message how to use your frickin' debugger before asking such questions here?

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error

Comment: _`char que[100];`_ Also use something better like `string que;` IIRC even ancient turbo c++ supported that.

Comment: Try using `strlen` on `que` to see how many characters are in your *string*.  BTW, spelling out variable names makes your code easier to read and easier to debug; the variable name doesn't affect execution time nor build time.

Comment: I tried to debug your program on my computer, but you are using `clrscr` which I don't have and also, I don't have your input file.  Looks like you'll have to debug your program for me.

Comment: Why are you using `getline` to read in a binary file?  Remember, `getline` will stop at the first *newline*.  So if your `que` variable in the structure has `\n` in it, the `getline` function won't read the second array.  Reminder:  if you use `write` for output, use `read` for input.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with the following changes:

1. Add `out.close()` after writing to the file to flush the output buffer.
2. Replace `getline` with `read`, to retrieve the bytes as `write` wrote them. `getline` might give different results under some conditions.
3. Move the read statement into the `while` condition:

   `while(in.read((char *) &d, sizeof(test)))`

With the read statement in the body of the loop `in.eof()` will not return true immediately after reading the last `test` object so the loop will then execute one last time.